# JAXL Library in PHP Receiving incoming data

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using JAXL library Version 2 and able to connect to server send presence and set status online. I am able also send messages to a particular user very well. this is all working very well.
So now i want to be able display incoming data upon arrival but some how i do not know how to do it.
I see a method called getMessage but i do not know how to use it since i do not which arguments to provide it with. It has two arguments $payload and $jaxl. My question is where do i get the $payload and $jaxl values to provide to this method. Is this the really method that gets incoming data like chat messages sent to me on chat.  i need help because the project is now on halt for that reaseon. I have searched the web and found no one has ever used this method get incoming data or have not seen anyone get incoming data by JAXL.

```
public static function getMessage($payloads, $jaxl) {
        $html = '';
        foreach ($payloads as $payload) {
            // reject offline message
            if ($payload['offline'] != JAXL0203::$ns && $payload['type'] == 'chat') {
                if (strlen($payload['body']) > 0) {
                    $html .= '<div class="mssgIn">';
                    $html .= '<p class="from">' . $payload['from'] . '</p>';
                    $html .= '<p class="body">' . $payload['body'] . '</p>';
                    $html .= '</div>';
                } else if (isset($payload['chatState']) && in_array($payload['chatState'], JAXL0085::$chatStates)) {
                    $html .= '<div class="presIn">';
                    $html .= '<p class="from">' . $payload['from'] . ' chat state ' . $payload['chatState'] . '</p>';
                    $html .= '</div>';
                }
            }
        }


        if ($html != '') {
            $response = array('jaxl' => 'message', 'message' => urlencode($html));
            $jaxl->JAXL0206('out', $response);
        }
        return $payloads;
    }
```